# Android SQLite 'user' table primary key for 'user log' primary key

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using an auto_increment primary key for the 'user' table. My question is, can I use that same User ID (Primary Key), as the primary key for the 'user log' table? Are there any major reasons why I shouldn't do this?

My idea on implementation:
To do this I would have the user create an entry (name,email pass, etc), once that's complete the 'User Log' is created by taking the key from the 'user' table and passing that into the 'user log' entry creation method as a foreign key? Or would it still be called the primary key at this point?

A simple code example would be great. Here is what I have:

```
// Create the table
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE userLog ( " +
            "userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
            "date TEXT )";
    // create directory table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USERLOG_TABLE);
}
//Add entry to the table using value from user
public void addEntry(UserLogEntry entry, UserEntry userEntry){
    Log.d("addEntry", entry.toString());
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_USERID, userEntry.getUserID()); 
    values.put(KEY_DATE, entry.getDate()); 

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_USERLOG, // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

    // 4. close
    db.close(); 
}
```

So that won't work thanks to CL for pointing that out. I'll need to have a unique key and add the userid's as a new column. I'll just pull the userid from the users table when creating the userslog and that should solve that issue.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 relationship between records in the `User` and `userLog` tables, or can there be multiple logs per user?

Comment: There can be multiple logs per user. Thanks for pointing that out. That thought hadn't occurred to me. Good save :)